# Как создать вёрстку для Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Хочу научится делать сайты на WordPress со своей вёрсткой (делать свои шаблоны).
В интернете много информации о том, как натягивать вёрстку на WordPress, но меня интересует какие требования есть для вёрстки которую я собираюсь интегрировать туда?
Можно делать любую вёрстку или нужно делать специально так, чтобы её можно поставить на WordPress?
То есть соответствующие меню, сайдбары и т.п?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Хочу научится делать сайты на WordPress со своей вёрсткой

Для этого нужно выбрать в [оф.каталоге](https://wordpress.org/themes/) тему, подходящую по структуре/макету и, создав к ней [дочернюю](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/), уже в дочке "верстать" то, что понадобится.
И ни в коем случае не нужно пытаться сделать "свою тему" пока не будет достаточно опыта в работе с ВП.

Необходимый минимум:
[Создание тем](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC)

[Иерархия шаблонов](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%98%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2)

[Теги шаблонов](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8_%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2)

> В интернете много информации о том как натягивать вёрстку на
> wordpress,

Не нужно читать и смотреть этот интернет-хлам.

> меня интересует какие требования есть для вёрстки которую я собираюсь
> интегрировать туда?

[Документация для разработчика](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0#.D0.A0.D0.B0.D0.B7.D1.80.D0.B0.D0.B1.D0.BE.D1.82.D0.BA.D0.B0_.D1.82.D0.B5.D0.BC)

[Стандарты кодирования НТМL](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D1%8B_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%9D%D0%A2%D0%9CL)

[Стандарты_кодирования_CSS](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D1%8B_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_CSS)

[Стандарты кодирования Javascript](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D1%8B_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_Javascript)

Comment: Спасибо за полезную информацию.

Comment: Ссылки очень полезные, но ты бы поставил их описание, типа "стандарты кодирования js" и т.п.

Comment: @SeVlad Здравствуйте что скажете про этот курс по WP https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7NNtOXgNPBM&list=PL3LQJkGQtzc6Nwz67GGrMdqxim1c0H5DC

Comment: @Leks ничего не скажу. Даже не пойду туда. Разве только то , что это надо смотреть чтобы что-то сказать.. А это "смотреть" - бесполезная трата времени.

Comment: @SeVlad откуда Вы знаете что бесполезная трата времени если не смотрели ?

Answer (score 1):

Нужно хоть немного познать PHP. А так - попробуйте скачать чистую WP-тему. http://dontforget.pro/wordpress/chistyiy-shablon-wordpress-dlya-razrabotki-2-0/ Почти все строки кода прокомментированы, будет немного легче все понять.

И.. "..кодекс надо чтить"

Comment: Вы можете дать более развёрнутый ответ?