# Поиск файлов с вёрсткой в wordpress файлах

Tags: wordpress

Всех с наступающим!

Такая ситуация: ко мне обратились за помощью - подвинуть текст в блоке.

Сайт создан на вордпресе и размещён на reg.ru

Покопавшись в файловом менеджере, не нашёл файла, в котором написан блок.

Index.php ссылается на второй файл, второй на третий и так далее.

С вордпрессом дел раньше не имел - всё писал ручками в студии.

Где находится файл/ы с вёрсткой?

Comment: wp-content/themes/тема. А почему не обратиться к документации вордпресс?

Comment: Даже не знал, что на такой случай она есть. Как уже говорил, с вордпресом никогда не работал.

Answer (score 1):

Не зная ВП и даже не подозревая о [документации](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC) - не нужно ничего трогать. Для безопасного изменения темы есть механизм [дочерних тем](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%94%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B). Иначе всё поломается при первом же обновлении.

См ответ [Как создать вёрстку для Wordpress?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/763176/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d1%91%d1%80%d1%81%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-wordpress/763199#763199)

Но безболезненно изменить стили можно из админки - внешний вид-настроить. Это называется кастомайзер.
В нём есть блок "дополнительные стили".

[image: кастомайзер]

Его положение может меняться в зависимости от используемой темы.

Comment: Суть в том, что мне нужно было изменить стиль одного заголовка (найти его код в файле и добавить style="color: black; float: right"), а не менять тему целиком или делать что-либо глобальное

Comment: @Nikita именно это я и показал. ..в прошлом году :)