# Не подключаются стили к Wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Пытаюсь из обычной html-страницы сделать тему для Wordpress, который стоит у меня локально. Отделил Header и Footer, в Header.php добавил wp_head(), а в functions.php добавил следующий код:

```
<?php
function mytheme_scripts() {
  wp_enqueue_style( 'main', get_template_directory_uri() . '/main.css');
  wp_enqueue_style( 'fonts', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/fonts.css');
  wp_enqueue_style( 'media', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/media.css' );
  wp_enqueue_script( 'common', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/common.js');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mytheme_scripts' );
```

Но, несмотря ни на что, таблицы стилей не подключаются (проверял через браузер). В чем может быть проблема?
После редактирования main.css у меня подключились все стили. Но скрипты подключаться не хотят.

Comment: Для выявления ошибок, я бы включил их отображение в wp_config.php

Comment: У меня включено. Иногда появляется ошибка, что не удаётся обновится в админке. Но на сайте ошибок не пишет, нет подключений стилей в исходном коде страницы, нет ощибок в консоли

Comment: У вас случайно тема не дочерняя? Можете выложить скриншот хромовской консоли! В слепую очень трудно разбираться!

Comment: Файл точно называется `functions.php`? Или как в тексте вопроса?

Comment: Консоли из инструмента разработчика? Там только JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed.

Comment: Да, functions.php, я только что проверил. Когда-нибудь научусь внимательно читать.

Comment: Главная ошибка новичков - делать "свои" темы. См https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/763176/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d1%91%d1%80%d1%81%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-wordpress/763199#763199

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В первую очередь, вынесите add_action из тела функции!

```
<?php
function mytheme_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'main', get_template_directory_uri() . '/main.css');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'fonts', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/fonts.css');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'media', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/media.css' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'common', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/common.js');

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mytheme_scripts' );
```

`get_template_directory_ur()` не содержит закрывающий слеш. Я исправил код.

Кроме того, если у вас в header.php нет вызова `wp_head()`, то весь ваш код работать не будет.

Comment: wp_head() есть,я хотел об этом написать,  слеш добавил, но это не помогло. Может ли быть, что у меня криво установился Wordpress?

Comment: Непонятно, чему там криво устанавливаться. В консоли что?

Comment: Ничего. Консоль пустая

Comment: Так у вас add_action внутри функции!!! Я только сейчас заметил. Обновил ответ.

Comment: Да, спасибо, я это упустил. К сожалению результата не дало. Я читал, не в кодексе, некоторые вставляют подключение стилей в хедер, у меня и там не работало.

Comment: Похоже на то, что этот код вообще у вас не исполняется. А должен. Трудно сказать, в чём дело. Скорее всего в том, что вы взялись создавать собственную тему в WordPress, не обладая должным опытом. Это типичная ошибка. Сначала надо учиться создавать дочернюю тему от стандартной, и там делать первые шаги - подключать стили, например.

Answer (score 0):

Была такая проблемка. Решил так, просто подключал стили через функцию

```
function main_load() { 
    $theme_uri = get_template_directory_uri(); 
    wp_register_style('main', $theme_uri.'/main.css', false, '0.1');
    wp_enqueue_style('main'); 
} 
add_action('main', 'main_load');
```