# Wordpress ищет темы не там, где нужно

Tags: php, wordpress

Вот содержание **function.php**

```
<?php
 add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'kompomir_style');

 function kompomir_style() {
    wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap-css', '/wp-content/themes/kompomircss/bootstrap.min.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style('fontawesome-css', get_template_directory_uri().'css/font-awesome.min.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style('iconstyle-css', get_template_directory_uri().'css/icon-styles.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style('animate-css', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/animate.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style('owl.carousel-css', get_template_directory_uri().'css/owl.carousel.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style('venobox-css', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/venobox.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style('font-wesome-css', get_template_directory_uri().'сss/font-awesome.min.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style('style-css', get_stylesheet_uti());
 }

 ?>
```

Но, стили не грузятся от куда нужно бы, а ВП ищет их в  http://wordpress/css/

Comment: Перед тем, как задать первый вопрос, прочитайте [справку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Пользуйтесь тегами правильно, чтобы вопрос был читаемым. Не забывайте пользоваться поиском, ведь есть [похожие темы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/809006/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BA-wordpress)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Не подключаются стили к Wordpress](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/809006/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%ba-wordpress)