# Wordpress переход на просто пустую страницу с заголовком

Tags: wordpress

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="">О компании</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Услуги</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Отзывы</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Контакты</a></li>
```

есть у меня задание по вордпрес, ранее никогда вообще не сталкивался с CMS ну вообще))))) сверстал тему, засунул ее в темы, замутил хедер, индекс пхп... вобщем все работает, запускается, но нужно зделать так, чтоб при нажатии на ссылки открывалась пустая страница с заголовком(данной лишки), сижу туплю день уже, подскажите как быть, с меня пиво, заранее спасибо !)

Comment: Создать страницу в админке. Меню и вообще ВСЁ, что касаемо контента создавать там же.. (Надеюсь, хоть не клиенту ты подсовываешь такою свинью)

Comment: Не, не клиенту, когда создаю новую страницу в админке, беру оттуда урл, и перехожу по ней, открваетса моя , но поломаная, с чем связано?

Comment: С кривой темой. Возьми тему из оф репо, сделай дочку и не ищи приключений на седалище https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/763176/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d1%91%d1%80%d1%81%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-wordpress/763199#763199

Comment: понимаеш, нада на самописной теме)) в том то и прикол

Comment: Нет, не понимаю. Я считаю это "надо" только ЧСВ, не более. А задача "сделать тему" вовсе не для новичков. Тем более правильно.  Но нет ничего не возможного - все маны есть по ссылке.