# Где хранится все содержимое страниц на Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Все никак не могу понять, где же хранится все содержимое страницы... Иной раз нужно удалить какой то класс у элемента или наоборот добавить, но как найти в PHP файлах нужный объект? я никак не могу понять структуру, как эти файлы выводятся...
Помогите, пожалуйста, объясните кто-нибудь.
Шаблон темы Enfold

Answer (score 1):

> Иной раз нужно удалить какой то класс у элемента или наоборот
>   добавить, но как найти в PHP файлах нужный объект?

Если имеются ввиду классы CSS, то они, обычно, находятся в файлах с расширением *.css или же *.less, *.saas если используется препроцессор.

Как их можно искать и редактировать:

1) В браузере, например, Google Chrome откройте "инструменты разработчика" - Ctrl+Shift+I или F12. Найдите CSS код элемента, который вы хотите отредактировать.

2) Если это хороший хостинг, то наверняка там будет какой-либо файловый менеджер. Найдите файлы, содержащие этот CSS код, через него. Если файлового менеджера на хостинге нет, то ищите код через FTP клиент (например, FileZilla).

3) Если это локальный сервер, то можно искать через Notepad++, или через какой-либо файловый менеджер.

Answer (score 0):

Копируете локально себе проект, открываете редактором Notepad++, phpStorm и т.д. и делаете поиск по файлам в phpStorm это `Find In Path`.

А вообще начните с изучения иерархии шаблонов, так будет легче понять где искать:
пост - single.php
страница - page.php
категория - archive.php

Но так же структура файлов может быть разбита на части `template-parts`.

Так же советую дополнить ваш вопрос реальным примером, если вы упомянули тему Enfold. Добавьте информацию, что примерно вы хотите найти.

*Добавлено описание:*

**Smart Slider 3**

У вас скорее всего стили кнопки будут выглядеть так:

```
div#n2-ss-3 .n2-font-75774b5a595fadfc3656349b99c5effa-link a {
    font-family: 'Montserrat','Arial';
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 100%;
    text-shadow: none;
    line-height: 1.5;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    word-spacing: normal;
    text-transform: none;
}
```

назначайте более высокий приоритет селекторам или свойствам и перебивайте стили.

Настройка кнопки [Docs](https://smartslider3.helpscoutdocs.com/article/319-button-layer)

Comment: я добавила слайдер от Smart Slider 3. На слайдере разместила кнопку, ее мне нужно немного изменит под себя. Смотрю исходный код- там к этой кнопке куча классов прописано (<div class="n2-ss-button-container n2-ow n2-font-72c1fdc336d6460a261f2baf0f8243c6-link  n2-ss-nowrap"><a class="n2-style-13feef46641adcb80c5df04f710c3b35-heading  n2-ow " "><div><div>Онлайн-заявка</div></div></a></div>). Вот где мне искать это?

Comment: То что вы указали, относится к коду слайдера, а не к коду темы. Поэтому нужно стили кнопки делать в настройках слайдера, если гибкости настройки нет, тогда перебивайте стилями

Comment: Добавил в ответе описание

Comment: Со стилями я так и делаю, а вот как где можно изменить ссылку и прописать для нее новый путь? Конкретно: в настройках слайдера в ссылку нельзя прописать шорткод(всплывающая форма), можно только #... Значит мне нужно в коде изменить для нее значение, обернув мою форму в див. Вот тут то я и не могу найти, где же мой слайдер хранит значение "a" И вообще, через PHP ли оно выводится? либо через JS? Извините за тупость:)

Comment: Адрес ссылки должен меняться в настройках слайдера - в этом я уверен. Выберите слой кнопки и перейдите в раздел настройки (там нарисована шестеренка)

Comment: Почему в каждом комментарии мы узнаем что-то новое. Отредактируйте свой вопрос так, чтоб там было понятно, что конкретно вы хотите сделать. Без лишнего текста, только конкретника

Comment: Посмотрите здесь https://smartslider3.helpscoutdocs.com/article/319-button-layer

Comment: Спасибо за внимание) Смогла вставить ссылку как мне требовалось только лишь заменив кнопку на текст со стилями. Разработчик также ответил, что это единственный выход

Comment: Создайте ответ и опишите свои действия там

Answer (score 0):

> где же хранится все содержимое страницы.

В базе данных. Но лазить в неё ненужно.

> Иной раз нужно удалить какой то класс у элемента или наоборот добавить, но как найти в PHP файлах нужный объект?

Это уже не содержимое, а верстка, разметка. За это отвечают файлы темы.

> я никак не могу понять структуру, как эти файлы выводятся...

https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%98%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2

См также [Как создать вёрстку для Wordpress?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/763176/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d1%91%d1%80%d1%81%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-wordpress/763199#763199)