# Stylesheet is missing wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Создал свою wordpress тему и пытался натянуть верстку, но выдает

> Stylesheet is missing.

Вот структура файлов
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Делаем темы правильно, учим документацию https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/763176/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d1%91%d1%80%d1%81%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-wordpress/763199#763199

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Файл стилей темы должен называться style.css.

Не styles.css.