# Как определить ID элемента в WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

Я с WP едва знаком, и столкнулся с небольшим непониманием: как узнать id определенного элемента в WordPress? Я подключаю свою тему к фреймворку и необходимо указать id элемента, чтобы, например, изменять цвет этого элемента, заменить элемент и т.п.

Я сперва создаю сайты в редакторе, а потом конвертирую в php. И идентификатором служил заданный элементу класс.

Вот я хочу, чтобы пользователь мог через настройки темы изменить цвет определенной секции. И требуется индивидуальный идентификатор. Ну вот где его взять?

Comment: Я думаю ця стаття вам допоможе
https://misha.blog/wordpress/kak-uznat-id-posta.html

Comment: Спасибо, но это ведь Id статей? А мне необходимы все элементы сайта: от Id, который отвечает за фавикон до id секции, див блока или еще чего либо

Comment: Выводите свой контент с идентификаторами. Сам WP их не вставляет в код html.

Comment: То есть мне в html в редакторе самостоятельно нужно дописать идентификатор? А как? Что именно писать?

Comment: Я не знаю, что вы там пишете. Пример приведите. Выводите свою секцию, добавляя в id в <section ... В чём проблема-то? WordPress тут при чём?

Comment: За внешний вид отвечает тема. Едва знакомым с ВП не стоит даже браться за написание своей и тем более "подключать" к какому-то там фреймворку (ибо ересь написана). Изучаем основы:  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/763176/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d1%91%d1%80%d1%81%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-wordpress/763199#763199

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю через php-функцию rand(1,9999); сформировать id для каждого типа элемента, и уже потом изменить стиль этого блока.