# Как добавить динамическую таблицу в WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Я создал верстку сайта на обычном HTML\CSS\JS , и я посадил верстку на WP, а теперь вопрос..

1. У меня есть таблица с collapse при клике на блок открывает таблицу, и мне нужно сделать таблицу чтобы она была динамическая, и чтобы ее можно было изменить в админке, потому что только верстку посадил на WP и я ничего не могу изменить в админке?
2. Где можно посмотреть информацию чтобы создать таблицу динамическую, или какой плагин использовать для таблиц?
3. И какая тема подходит лучше всего если ты садишь верстку на WP?

Первый раз делаю такое, поэтому простите за тупые вопросы.

Большое Спасибо !

Comment: Где эта таблица с `collapse` располагается? Для правки чего-то в админке должна быть соответствующим образом сконфигурирована тема. Если эта ваша таблица располагается в какой-то странице, то и правьте код этой страницы в админке, если вы конечно не всунули весь `html css js` в `php` файлы.

Comment: Да я всю верстку засунул в php.  Я нашел например как сделать меню динамическим а вот таблицу не могу так сделать

Comment: Не суйте всю вёрстку (контент) в `php`. Создавайте файлы шаблонов, в файле шаблонов выводите контент, а в админке наполняйте страницу контентом.

Comment: Хорошо, а какую лучше тему выбрать для верстки, чтобы создавать файлы шаблонов и выводить их ? Или это любую тему можно использовать

Comment: Используйте любую тему, а ещё лучше - напишите свою. Чесно говоря, не знаю тем, в которых файлы шаблонов можно создавать прямо в админке, обычно они создаются с специальными комментариями в начале файла, по которым WP понимает что этот `php` файл - шаблон. После создания файла-шаблона, вы можете задать шаблон для страницы в админке. Навык писать темы для WP - обязательный, если хотите в дальнейшем разрабатывать под `WordPress`

Comment: Берите любую тему из официального репозитория WordPress, создавайте от неё дочернюю и модифицируйте как хотите.

Comment: Я хочу просто свой сайт посадить на WP, поэтому не знаю стоит ли учить мне php.. А еще подскажите пожалуйста хорошие уроки по созданию тем? Буду очень благодарен !

Comment: @Klimenkomud я бы категорически не рекомендовал начинать с разработки своей темы. Это просто убие время, и куча нелепых вопросов здесь на SO. Надо сначала разобраться, как устроена нормальная современная тема, а потом уже плодить свои велосипеды.

Comment: Спасибо , пойду разбираться с этим вопросом !

Comment: @KAGGDesign Два пути, которые приводят к +/- одинаковому результату. Соглашусь с вами, лучше сначала разобрать как устроены хорошо написанные темы, а потом уже писать свою.

Comment: @Klimenkomud и вот снова то же самое: "Грешу на то что я создал кривую тему, но кривизну найти не могу." https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/865309/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%83-%D1%83%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-slug-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8

Comment: Однозначно - выкинуть свою самописку и использовать темы из репо, создав дочку См https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/763176/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d1%91%d1%80%d1%81%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-wordpress/763199#763199