# Дублирование элементов Wordpress(Woocommerce)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cms

Есть сайт WP на Woocommerce. 
https://englishinna.ru/product/videorolik-56/
Пытаюсь сделать нормальную карточку товара, о она отображается не так, как нужно.

Сам движок и плагин обновлены до последних версий. 
Как и положено скопировал папку вукомерса(tamplate) в папку с моей темой(самописной).
Стилизирую страницу товара хуками в файле `single.php`. Но в таком случае не отображаются картинки рекомендуемых и похожих товаров внизу.

Если прописать просто `<?php woocommerce_content(); ?>`, то начинает дублировать элементы. Одни, которые в центре дублирует как нужно, а "внешние тогда нужно убирать". Перерыл все файлы что были. удалял все что можно, но не удаляется. Подскажите пожалуйста, что делать? Если нужно - могу дать админку.

Comment: Что делать? Взять нормальную тему из оф каталога. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/763176/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d1%91%d1%80%d1%81%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-wordpress/763199#763199

Answer (score 0):

Кому интересно - решил этот вопрос другим путем. А именно, вставил две строчки в файл single.php:

```
<?php 
    $id = $product->get_id();
    echo do_shortcode('[product_page id="'.$id.'"]'); 
?>
```

Применил шорткод вывода товара по идентификатору. А в id ставлю id текущей страницы.
Может быть и костыль, но работает. Пользуйтесь))