# Не могу вложить footer в div.wrapper

Tags: php, html, wordpress

У меня есть верстка и нужно её натянуть на вордпрессе. Всё бы хорошо во только не получается вложить фоотер в div.wrapper . Вот header.php код

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <main class="main" role="main">
          <header></header>
```

А тут вот footer.php код

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying the footer
 *
 * Contains the closing of the #content div and all content after.
 *
 * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-files/#template-partials
 *
 * @package AXILinteriors
 */

?>
</div>
 <footer></footer>
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Попробовал убрать закрывающийся div, тогда footer становится дочерним элементом main, если поставить два закрывающейся diva то ничего не происходит.  мне надо что бы он был дочерним элементом div.wrapper

Comment: Что делает хедер в боди, а футер до вызова функции футера? Выкинь этот хлам и возьми нормальную тему из оф каталога https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/763176/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d1%91%d1%80%d1%81%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-wordpress/763199#763199

Comment: Это тема c undescores.me! Про header в body не понял, вроде там его место, не класть же его в head! Но учту про хлам, спасибо !

Comment: А, сорри, c header погорячился (показалось head). Но тем не менее - не занимайся фигнёй, не бери никакие underscores и тп. Бери темы из оф каталога, делай дочку и изменяй в ней что надо.

Comment: Спасибо, учту !