# Конфликт AJAX contact form 7 и скриптов в шаблоне (Не работает отправка без перезагрузки страницы))

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, contact-form7

Есть сайт на Wordpress. Вот страница этого сайта http://kluch-ok.ru/services/remote/

Отправка формы работает только с перезагрузкой страницы.

Методом отключения-подключения выяснил, что конфликтует Contact Form 7 со скриптом http://kluch-ok.ru/wp-content/themes/spla/js/main.js?ver=4.9.8

И вот не понятно что именно не нравится? Удалял ajax подгрузку контента из файла. Не помогает.

Помогите советом. Третий день тыркаюсь.

Comment: Обратись к разработчику темы

Comment: Я и есть разработчик темы!

Comment: Это печально :) https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/763176/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d1%91%d1%80%d1%81%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-wordpress/763199#763199