# Мобильная версия сайта, как лучше сделать?

Tags: wordpress, css3, html5, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка

Будет делаться сайт на WordPress и его потом нужно не просто адптировать с помощью медиа-запросов, а сделать для него отдельную мобильную версию.

Можете дать, пожалуйста, советы как в целом такое делается, это нужно сначала на основном домене установить WordPress и сделать десктопную версию, а потом на поддомене для мобильной версии еще раз устанавливать WordPress и опять с нуля делать интеграцию?

Или мобильную версию возможно сделать в одной установке WordPress?

Comment: Почему Вы не хотите саделать один сайт с адаптивной версткой, как под мобильные, так и под десктоп? Конечно разделять на два сайта тоже глупо, так как придеться редактировать тексты и там и там, разве что можно будет через User-Agent проверять с какого устройства зашел пользователь.

Comment: @WanSpi я полностью согласен, но заказчик хочет сделать именно отдельную мобильную версию

Comment: Нужны именно два домена, отдельно для мобильной и отдельно для десктопной?

Comment: @WanSpi, вот это я хотел узнать как лучше будет, два разных домена нужно или как-то на одном можно будет сделать

Comment: конечно что то такое не делал на WP, но думаю есть плагины специально под это, как вариант предварительно, проверять UserAgent в шаблоне, и отдавать нужные блоки, а на счет разных доменов, лучше все таки один, либо же если два, то что бы они смотрели на одну и ту же папку, можно сказать что бы был один сайт, только под разные домены.

Comment: Давайте так: почему заказчик хочет сделать именно отдельную мобильную версию?

Comment: @andreymal потому что заказчик - дебил. На днях гугл начал рассылку сообщений типа "Ооо, ваш мобил сайт совпадает с десктопным, круто. Поднимем в рейтинге"

Answer (score 0):

> и его потом нужно не просто адптировать с помощью медиа-запросов, а
>   сделать для него отдельную мобильную версию.

Не нужно никаких "потом". Нужно сразу выбрать подходящую по макету тему из [оф каталога](https://wordpress.org/themes/) и убедиться что она адаптивная (не адаптивных сейчас наверное и нет). А при необходимости кастомизации - использовать [механизм дочерних тем](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%94%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B).

И не понятно зачем "отдельная мобильная версия" в 21 веке, но для этого есть плагины.  По сути они подменяют тему для моб. устройств.

Comment: тему я буду свою делать, брать верстку и делать потом интеграцию. Заказчик хочет именно отдельную мобильную версию сделать, а не просто адаптивно сверстать сайт

Comment: Не вздумай! Не льсти себе и не подставляй заказчика. См https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/763176/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%91%D1%80%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-wordpress/763199#763199

Comment: @SeVlad откуда Вы знаете его возможности? Тут задан конкретный вопрос, а не нужно это делать или нет, ничего зазорного в создании своих шаблонов я не вижу.

Comment: @WanSpi, возможности и квалификация прекрасно видны из вопроса. (Твоя ксати, тоже. "[Шаблоны](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%A7%D0%90%D0%92%D0%9E/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F)" :) . Читай по ссылке выше). Да и  как раз показатель квалификации - только нубы с завышенным ЧСВ и не пониманием ВП будет делать и советовать делать свои темы. А знающие ВП никогда такого не посоветуют.

Comment: @SeVlad прошу не переходить на грубости, я занимаюсь веб-разработкой уже не один год, и тоже знаю о чем говорю, шаблоном (https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Веб-шаблон) называют визуальное оформление, и я не советую создавать его, а просто говорю что нету ничего зазорного в этом

Comment: @WanSpi какие-такие грубости? Констатация факта. Незнание терминологии предмета и тем более обозначающие РАЗНОЕ  - прекрасный показатель квалификации. Учись, а не огрызайся. и всё у тебя получится.

Comment: Многие крупные проекты используют мобильную версию (не адаптивную) и ничего в этом плохого нет в 21 веке (какая вобще связь?).
У отдельной мобильной версии есть достаточно большой ряд преимуществ.

Comment: @Nilsan 
Отдельная моб версия МОЖЕТ быть нужна только в особых случаев. Тогда это касается не только "внешнего вида". Мало вероятно, что тут как раз тот случай. В 99% случаев адаптива достаточно выше крыши.

Comment: @SeVlad ну вопрос в топике поставлен достаточно просто "Как?". 
Вариант можно ли обойтись адаптивом уже лежит на плечах автора и как я думаю скорее всего не хватает навыков\знаний чтобы объяснить заказчику что этого делать в его случае ненужно, а либо тупо заказчик из категории "Я так хочу" :-)

Comment: @Nilsan совершено согласен :). И поэтому я не только дал ответ на вопрос "как", но прежде всего пытался донести правильное решение.

Comment: @SeVlad Заказчика надо заставить гуглить mobile first и поднятие рейтинга за идентичность мобильной и десктопной версии сайта. Все мои сайты уже получили статус "Mobile-first indexing enabled". Просто потому, что сделаны на адаптивных темах.

Comment: @KAGGDesign ну не надо его такому заставлять. а вот показав ТОП и рекомендации ПС они уже начинают задумываться.