# Что изучить перед изучением WordPress?

Tags: html, wordpress

Хочу научиться натягивать верстку на вордпресс. Владею html, css, pug, saas и на начальном уровне js.
Погуглив, нашла разные ответы - одни говорят, что перед изучением вордпрес нужно хорошо знать php, другие говорят, что нужно хорошо знать javascript. Третьи - что достаточно просто html+css.

Что же все таки нужно изучить перед началом изучения WordPress?

Comment: php, mysql, javascript, html, css

Comment: Смотря какие проекты. Для начала достаточно немного php и js

Comment: HTML/CSS - однозначно, PHP/MySQL/JS - хотя бы немного понимать

Comment: английский язык для начала так как на русском ни чего путного нету и документацию wordpress ну и разумеется вёрстку + jquery как минимум

Comment: @UbuntuUser на русском есть отличная документация по WordPress, на сайте kama.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/763176/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d1%91%d1%80%d1%81%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-wordpress/763199#763199

Comment: Можете вот здесь еще немного почитать, для начала может хватит, а дальше нужно развиваться https://misha.blog/wordpress/php-for-wordpress.html