# Wordpress и навигация

Tags: wordpress

Уже пару-тройку дней вожусь с вордпрессом на локалхосте.
На каком-то сайте взял верстку блога 2007 года и натягиваю ее на вп.

В верстке есть вот такая шапка, где "culinary" - ссылка на домашнюю страницу
(ссылку на нее я сделал через `get_home_url()`)
и обычное меню, которое я сделал средствами WP - меню страниц.

И наконец вопрос: как сделать так, что бы у меня домашняя страница была "home" **И** на эту страницу выводились последние посты?

[image: шапка]
Если в админке home назначить и главной страницей, и страницей с записями, то  будет следующая ситуация:
урл -

```
http://culinary/
```

на страницу выводятся другие страницы..
[image: страница]

а при урле -

```
http://culinary/home/
```

на который можно попасть только введя урл в строку поиска - уже выводятся посты 
и "home" выделена [image: посты]

написано все криво, косо, но думаю суть вопроса понятна))
кстати, нажатие на "culinary" и "home" в меню - отправляет меня на 
    `http://culinary/`

Comment: Выкинь всё, начиная с "локалхоста". Кури https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/763176/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d1%91%d1%80%d1%81%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-wordpress/763199#763199. ЗЫ. 2007й. Ппц. Сообщаю новость - вчера 2019й наступил.

Comment: @SeVlad а что плохого в локалхосте? да и в верстке 2007? верстка она и в 007 верстка.. шаблон простой - вот я его и взял; шапка, контентная часть с потсами, сайдбар с рубриками и футер..

Comment: @SeVlad окей, если без локалхоста - предлагаешь выкинуть все это на сервак, и при добавлении любой запятой аплоадить файлы?

Comment: 1. "в локалхосте"  плохо всё - начиная от др. среды разработки и заканчивая отсутствием возможности показать проблему. 2. "Верстка".. Колесо и в 13м веке было колесом, но на СОВРЕМЕННОМ транспорте оно  несколько другое. НО это вопросы не для обсуждения на данном ресурсе. Хочешь "поговорить" - это можно сделать на любом на форуме (лучше на [офиц](https://ru.wordpress.org/support/)). А как *правильно* работать с темами ВП - я тебе дал ссылку.

Comment: А, и да! "Верстка" и "тема ВП" - вещи совершенно разные.

Answer (score 0):

> И наконец вопрос: как сделать так, что бы у меня домашняя страница
>   была "home" И на эту страницу выводились последние посты?

Назначить главной любую страницу кроме "home", а вот её - страницей ленты.