# Товары из woocommerce не отображаются

Tags: woocommerce

Я установил плагин WooCommerce. Добавил товар. 
В functions.php добавил код

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'woocommerce_support' );
    function woocommerce_support() {
        add_theme_support( 'woocommerce' );
    }
```

создал копию page.php переименовал на woocommerce.php и там поставил вместо цикла вывода постов

```
<? woocommerce_content();?>
```

Но получается так: товаров нету и надпись отображается все 3 результатов
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Шаблон я сам делал поэтому мог что то упустить

Answer (score 0):

> создал копию page.php

Надо в теме создать каталог `woocommerce` и уже в него копировать шаблоны из каталога `templates` плагина.
См https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/third-party-custom-theme-compatibility/

> Шаблон я сам делал поэтому мог что то упустить

[Как создать вёрстку для Wordpress?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/763176/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%91%D1%80%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-wordpress/763199#763199)