# Собрать тему из нескольких Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Много кто работает на  Wordpress знает бесплатную тему Sydney.
Вот ссылка https://athemes.com/theme/sydney/

Так вот там мне очень нравится главный слайдер.
Есть другие темы для Wordpress и там красивые разные штуки ( виджеты дизайн страниц и тд.)

Интересует вопрос делал ли кто-то свою тему на Wordpress собирая ее из нескольких тем.

Думаю попробовать взять чистую тему. Начать с файлов index.php style.css и скиывать шаблоны из других тем что понравились.
В итоге хотел бы получить что-то приблизительно как на фото.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблемма заключается в том что сначала хотел перенести блок из Cheerup и уперся во фреймворк на котором я так понял висит функционал. Очень много файлов из всеми плагинами вперемешку.

```html
// Initialize Framework
require_once get_template_directory() . '/lib/init.php';

// Fire up the theme - make available in Bunyad::get('cheerup')
Bunyad::register('cheerup', array(
 'class' => 'Bunyad_Theme_Cheerup',
 'init' => true
));
```

Когда пытался вытащить слайдер из темы Sydney то уперся опять же в то что 
он состоит из многих файлов которые находятся в разных папках. И все их вытащить пока что не пытался....

Скажите реально ли взять на свою тему повесить самое понравившееся из других тем, чтобы оно работало?

Comment: Открой для себя [механизм дочерних тем](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/) и почитай https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/763176/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d1%91%d1%80%d1%81%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-wordpress/763199#763199 и https://ru.wordpress.org/support/topic/%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%b0/#post-303672

Comment: Все можно. Многие так и делают. Но для этого надо обладать достаточным уровнем знания php.