# Реализация динамического текста на странице в WordPress

Tags: wordpress, веб-программирование, cms

Нужно натянуть верстку на WP с возможностью редактировать любой текст на сайте через админку. Получилось сделать динамический текст с помощью цикла:

```
<?php if (have_posts()): while (have_posts()): the_post(); ?>
<?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

, но только в каком то одном месте на странице и только один участок текста, а как сделать чтобы можно было редактировать весь текст на страннице ?

Comment: Натигивают презерватив... А тебе рано делать свои темы https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/763176/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%91%D1%80%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-wordpress/763199#763199

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в том, что функция the_content() выводит содержимое поста, а не всей страницы в целом.
Если вы хотите менять какие то блоки на странице, которые не относятся к содержимому записи, то воспользуйтесь плагином **Advanced custom fields(ACF)**.

Comment: Некорректная, я бы даже сказал правильная формулировка. последнего предложения Воспользоваться **произвольными полями**. А АCF - всего лишь один из сножесва плагинов для удобно управления ими. И вообще совершено не обязательный для работы с ПП.

Comment: Да, разумеется. И вообще помимо ACF есть carbon fields и другие плагины. А по поводу создания мета-полей можно почитать и в кодексе