# Создание темы с нуля WP?

Tags: wordpress, вёрстка

Всем привет. Есть сайт, который нужно перенести на WP(всего страниц 50-60). Главная страница сверстана(с новым дизайном и семантикой) и готова к посадке на WP. Вопрос: на внутренних страницах одинаковые heder\footer, которые будут подхватываться из heder, footer php, но внутрений контент в каждой странице разный, с уникальным дизайном и контентом. Получается нужно верстать каждую страницу с уникальным контентом, и каждую отдельно садить на WP, делая дочерние шаблоны от главного?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Получается нужно верстать каждую страницу с уникальным контентом, и
>   каждую отдельно садить на WP, делая дочерние шаблоны от главного?

Нет. "Верстать" придется только нужные шаблоны. Но это не то, то ты думаешь. Матчасть: [Иерархия шаблонов](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%98%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2)

А вообще не нужно вообще делать тему "с нуля". Нужно в оф.каталоге выбрать подходящую по макету и сделав к ней [дочернюю](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/) изменять в ней только нужные шаблоны и стили. См ещё [Как создать вёрстку для Wordpress?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/763176/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d1%91%d1%80%d1%81%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-wordpress/763199#763199)

Comment: Плюсанул, поддерживаю)

Comment: А разве не стоит использовать underscores для создания темы? Или это не самый лучший вариант при натягивания своего шаблона?

Comment: @Underdoggit намного не лучше.