# Как менять контент своего шаблона WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

Я учусь натягивать свой HTML шаблон на WordPress, я уже научился делать меню про помощи `wp_nav_menu();`

**Вопрос**: у меня есть блок с номером телефона и адресом. Как сделать так, чтобы я мог эти значения менять через админку?

Так же, на главной странице у меня есть такой блок с картинками и текстом:
[image: блок с картинками и текстом]

Эти картинки и текст так же хочу менять через админку.

Возможно есть какой-то плагин, что позволяет это делать? 
Или как это реализовать в коде. И как оно будет выглядеть в админке?

Объясните, пожалуйста, так как я только начал изучать и сложно понимаю как работает WordPress.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/763176/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d1%91%d1%80%d1%81%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-wordpress/763199#763199

Comment: Блоки вроде номера телефона и адреса удобно занести в кастомайзер https://wp-kama.ru/handbook/theme/customize-api

Comment: Блок с картинками и текстом лучше всего создать в блочном редакторе, например, Гутенберг или Элементор, и добавить свои стили для отображения согласно макету.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Лучше всего решает проблему плагин **Advanced Custom Fields**
На сайте плагина все детально описано https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/
Достаточно в шаблон вставить небольшой код и вывести в админку поле нужного типа (от текста, изображения до гугл карты)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй посмотреть туториалы на ютубе)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u_3BfxwkjWw

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WFEgmNfvpnw