# Натяжка уникальной верстки на билдер WP

Tags: html, css, wordpress, вёрстка

Вообщем есть уникальный дизайн. Необходимо привязать к WP с возможностью редактирования контента из админки. Как это делать через кастомные записи и через кастомизатор темы я вкурсе, но как я заметил в готовых темах с Themeforest везде прям используются билдеры Elementor или WP Backery.

Отсюда вопрос. Как вы считаете можно ли накидать контент на билдере и потом с помошью определения классов для элементов стилизовать так как нужно в итоге.

Заказчик хочет менять контент в визуальном редакторе. Или предложите пожалуйста ваши методики реализации подобных задач. Заранее Спасибо Большое!

Comment: Часть можно, но тут тоже нужно разбираться более подробно с билдером. Если вы первый раз работаете с билдером, то лучше делайте свои кастомные блоки полностью

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Полностью редактируемый контент в WP Backery: https://polati.ru/

Полагаю, это закрывает тему.

Comment: Я так полагаю это был уникальный дизайн, который натянут на WP Backery. Так? То есть своим ответом, вы хотите сказать, что всё возможно и это норм решение? Что скажете насчет Elementor vs. WP Backery?

Comment: Да, это уникальный дизайн, который я реализовал в WP Bakery. Всё возможно, и это нормальное решение, в отличие от так называемой "натяжки" на WordPress, когда в готовую вёрстку втыкают php-куски. В результате, получается нередактируемый сайт. В моём примере заказчик может править любые тексты в смысловых блоках.

Comment: Elementor - более современная технология. Сайты получаются более лёгкие и быстрые. Сделать полностью редактируемый сайт, как в примере с polati, тоже не проблема.

Comment: Спасибо за информацию. Я так понимаю процесс выглядит так... Верстаем хидер футер, делаем области для изменения через кастомайзер темы, остальной контент накидываем в билдере и потом уже стилизуем через кастомные стили, так? А вот вопрос... если мне нужно в билдер воткнуть кастомный логический блок, например калькулятор самописный, делаем через шорткод, так? Я вот видел, что люди пишут для билдеров свои собственные элементы. Когда это разумно использовать? И если можно ссылку на гайд какой нить, если имеется. Заранее спасибо большое!

Comment: Примерно так, да. Кастомные вещи через шорткоды, да. Можно и кастомные блоки создавать, но смысл имеет только при множественном использовании внутри проекта или на нескольких проектах.

Answer (score 0):

> есть уникальный дизайн. Необходимо привязать к WP с возможностью
>   редактирования контента из админки.
>   ...
>   Как вы считаете можно ли накидать контент на билдере и потом с помошью
>   определения классов для элементов стилизовать так как нужно в итоге.

Я считаю это ересью и злом для заказчика.

Нужно делать тему. А еще лучше - дочернюю тему к подходящей из оф каталога.

См [Как создать вёрстку для Wordpress?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/763176/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d1%91%d1%80%d1%81%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-wordpress/763199#763199)