# CMS для интернет-магазина, в которую легко дабавить свой HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, wordpress, cms

Есть готовый макет интернет-магазина на HTML/CSS. Пытался реализовать его на WordPress, однако я не знаю, как создать там свою тему, нет навыков работы с PHP. Я установил тему Астра и при помощи плагина Elementor пытался создавать тему с нуля. Однако возникли трудности, в частности тот факт, что в теме указаны по умолчанию свои свойства для размера и шрифта параграфов, марджинов различных блоков и т.п. Я прописывал кастомные CSS при помощи !important, однако это не всегда помогало. Подскажите, какой самый рациональный выход из данной ситуации, чтобы не было противоречий между моим CSS и CSS темы. Возможно, есть другие CMS, где будет все проще реализовать.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/763176/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%91%D1%80%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-wordpress/763199#763199 + документацию к Астре.(Это одна из немногих мощнейших тем с офигитеным функционалом под капотом)

Answer (score 0):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u_3BfxwkjWw

Посмотри, Артем доступным языком рассказывает на примере как натянуть верстку на WP.

А вообще можете bitrix попробовать, но там все более печально без php так как там сообщество не очень