# Посадка верстки на Wordpress. Очередность. Есть ли смысл писать скрипты слайдеров сразу или в процессе натяжки на WP?

Tags: wordpress, вёрстка, cms

Прошу не кидать тапками, это мой самый первый опыт посадки верстки на админку в целом и на WordPress в частности.  
А вопрос вот в чем: 
подготовила верстку интернет-магазина html и css, адаптировала под разные разрешения экрана. Но есть там 2 галлереи с фотографиями, скрипты к ним еще не писала. Стоит заморачиваться и писать Js заранее или потом уже проще плагин вордпресса установить и настроить показ слайдов?

Comment: смотря что считать проще. если вы знаете, что для показа галерей будут использоватся плагины. то стили придется править. если нет - можете смело подключать библиотеки слайдеров в теме и стилилзировать как хочется с "рыбой"

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/763176/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%91%D1%80%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-wordpress/763199#763199