# Wordpress. Добавить класс в отрывок (excerpt)

Tags: wordpress

Требуется стилизовать отрывки (excerpt).

В Wordpress отрывок обёрнут в тэг `<article>`, при этом не имеющий в себе никаких признаков этого самого отрывка — ни `id`, ни `class`. Испробовал предлагаемые интернетиком варианты кода для `functions.php`, но они обычно касаются параграфов и стилизовать блоки `article` никак не помогают (да и вообще не сработали у меня). А нужно всего лишь добавить лишний класс в `<article>` там, где применяются отрывки — в ленте Главной, в архивах и тому подобного контента. Темка-полигон одна из родных WP — «Twenty Twenty».

Подскажите пожалуйста корректный код для моей задачи.

Comment: Стилизуют с пом css. а не в functions.php. Вообще в него не лезь.

Comment: Стилизуют в *.css потом, после правки в functions.php. А чтобы стилизовать, сначала нужно добавить соответствующий код в functions.php. Это азы. Теперь нужен корректный код для внесения нового класса, размещаемого внутри <article>. Ну это тоже азы, кстати.

Comment: Азы описаны [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/763176/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%91%D1%80%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-wordpress/763199#763199) и [тут](https://wpmag.ru/2014/functions-php/).  А ты не понимаешь что делаешь. Но к сож SO не позволяет провести ликбез, так что..

Comment: Не провести ликбез может помешать лишь заскок ЧСВ, либо отсутствие знаний. Я, к примеру, спеца из себя не строю. Потому и обращаюсь как раз за ликбезом. И — уверен — по адресу. Не стесняйтесь показать свои знания.

Comment: Ещё раз: SO не позволяет провести ликбез. Это не его формат. Это сервис - "вопрос-ответ", а не форум и не чат. (Это был мини-лекбез по SO ;) )

Answer (score 0):

Первый вариант

1. создаёшь дочернюю тему
2. корректируешь нужный шаблон, в котором добавишь класс

Второй вариант. Можно проверить возможность добавления своего класса через хуки в functions.php:

```
add_filter('post_class', 'category_id_class');
add_filter('body_class', 'category_id_class');
```

---

UPD 27.08.2021

```
function add_my_class($classes, $class, $post_id){
//просто добавляем
      $classes[] = 'my-class';
    return $classes;
}

$my_excerpt = get_the_excerpt();
//если excerpt не пусто
if ( $my_excerpt ){
     add_filter('post_class', 'add_my_class');
}
```

Предельно упрощённое решение.
Опять же, это в шаблоне поста, дочерней темы добавлять.

Либо если делать в functions, то делать проверку get_the_excerpt на наличие excerpt уже внутри функции add_my_class.

Должно работать.

Comment: Понятно, что article — вовсе не обёртка excerpt, у отрывка она своя. Но задача изначально сформулирована чётко: нужно добавить в article класс-признак наличия excerpt, чтобы впоследствии стилизовать именно article. Всё-таки именно он представляет собой вид отрывка в ленте целиком. Я специалист совсем в другом деле (делаю людям больно, чтобы потом не было больно, обращайтесь), потому и прошу специалистов в WP, показать код, подходящий моей задаче. А уж в functions.php я его уж как-нибудь, так и эдак.

Comment: "А нужно всего лишь добавить лишний класс в <article> там, где применяются отрывки" - нет ни слова про условие. Раз с некорректной постановкой задачи разобрались, хочу спросить: что мешает добавить проверку? Если есть excerpt, то запускаем фильтр. Отступление: Суть в том, что если уж полез, то мучься, разбирайся (понимаю, причин может несколько: нет денег на программиста или сам начинающий программист или нравиться заниматься мазохизмом). Я встречал разных людей. И тут уж если полез в это гуано, то не испачкаться не получиться. Либо учиться и ковыряться в нём, либо обращаться к специалистам.

Comment: Добавил в ответ вариант решения.