# Внедрение своей верстки в шаблон WP

Tags: wordpress

Ситуация следующая. Нужно внедрить свою верстку в уже имеющийся шаблон (header, footer, и желательно чтобы функционал который был до этого никуда не делся). Мб у кого есть нормальные туториалы, ибо того что мне нужно найти не могу.

Comment: Создаёте дочернюю тему по отношению к уже имеющейся. https://codex.wordpress.org/Дочерние_темы

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/763176/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d1%91%d1%80%d1%81%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-wordpress/763199#763199

Comment: Есть хороший, понятный туториал на ютубе, канал "Глоакадемик", там лысый из браузера понятно объясняет как сверстать и натянуть свой шаблон на WP.