# Как сделать так, чтоб картинка загруженная в header в Wordpress появлялась на каждой странице сайта, где есть header?

Tags: wordpress

Впервые переношу верстку на Wordpress. Научился создавать шаблоны страниц, с помощью плагина "Advanced Custom Fields" создаю поля, которые можно в админке заполнять для каждой новой страницы. Но не могу найти инфу как сделать одно поле, которые загружало бы одну картинку в header и сразу на все страницы сайта. Сейчас у меня Лого загружается только для главной страницы сайта. На других страницах картинка пропадает.

Comment: header подключаю через bloginfo( 'template_url' ). Файл темы лежит в папке "templates", в корне темы.

Comment: Выкинь это всё и учи матчасть https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC.  И заодно читай https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/763199

Comment: @AndreyZavyalov Если в header и на все страницы сайта, Вам нужна или страница опций (ее можно сделать при помощи [ACF](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/options-page/), можно конечно и без ACF, но раз уж Вы его используете, будет логичнее) или опция добавленная через кастомайзер [Theme Customization API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Customization_API)

Comment: @Simon у acf вроде option page доступен в pro версии, но если автор поищет на кама есть пример создания страницы настроек используя функции wp

Answer (score 0):

Если я Вас правильно понял, вы выбрали условие для поля - "конкретная страница" или просто страница, но у Вас на сайте есть много других, ситуативных шаблонов. В частности page, post, archive и т.д. и т.п., в том числе 404.
В связи с чем, Вам надо прописывать условия ACF для того и для того и для того...
Не отрицаю способа и видел подмену фона, стилей для разных разделов и страниц (сам чудил в 1С-битрикс нечто подобное для разделов), но в этом случае надо понимать, что у Вас должны быть созданы отдельно ACF поля для картинки в страницах/постовах
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
и для разделов и отдельно,
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

поскольку вызов может отличаться.
Ну и для остальных, которые могут не вписаться в вашу затею с проверкой.

**А в целом, я не уверен, что разумно лого менять не через ХЭАДЕР, сквозным методом, а мудрить огород в ACF...**

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо за ответы. Я уже решил вопрос, и уже сделал.

Там все проще оказалось, чем я думал. Я не через ACF сделал, а через стандартный функционал WP. Я просто думал, что только через ACF можно делать динамично меняющиеся поля.