# Нет выбора шаблона на странице редактирвоания

Tags: wordpress

В свойства страницы не могу выбрать шаблон страницы.
Тема самописная. Шаблоны лежат в templates.
style.css:

```
/*
Theme Name: test
Author: test
Version: 0.1
*/
```

Comment: Лучше покажите что у Вас в шаблоне страницы.

Comment: Потому что взялся делать свои самописьки, не изучив даже основы. Это код **не шаблона**. А шаблоны должны лежать в корне. См https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/763199/233741