# Не вставляется верстка в вордпресс

Tags: wordpress

Смотрю видео, как натянуть верстку на вордпресс. Ничего не получается. Я зарегистрировала домен и оплатила хостинг. Там сначала я подставила верстку в главную папку, но потом я оттуда все удалила и переместила в `/public_html/wp-content/themes/vladim` (создала свою тему). Все поместила как надо, и уже в `page.php` добавила свою первую страницу верстки (как показали в видео). Но у меня ничего не отображается, я пробовала по-разному и в `index.php` - ничего. Я запуталась.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В этой папке, которую выделила, должен быть какой-то код? Может, направление в папку с вордпрессом, потому что, когда я туда вставляю верстку, на сайте отображается страница.

Comment: Уделите внимание грамотности вашего текста. Невозможно же читать. Я исправил штук 20 ошибок в двух абзацах.

Comment: учту, спасибо вам, очень помогли

Comment: Ваш код должен быть в теме, эта тема в свою очередь должна быть активирована, увидеть результат работы шаблона `page.php` можно создав страницу в админке. Из Вашего потока мысле ничего не понятно толком. Тот файл который Вы выделили, вообще не должен редактироваться, так как это файл самого движка.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/763176/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%91%D1%80%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-wordpress/763199#763199 а не вредные кино смотерть

Comment: @KAGGDesign, фактически, если не учитывать "волдпрес", то грамматических ошибок было 4, остальное было корректно, либо почти корректно, в частности не было необходимости изменять везде пунктуацию.

Answer (score -1):

Вы взяли какой-нибудь шаблон для создания темы? Существует базовый набор файлов, который должен содержаться в теме, иначе Вы вряд ли увидите ее даже в админке вордпресса, т.к. тема будет считаться "сломанной".
После того, как Вы соберете этот набор (index.php, styles.css + другие файлы по желанию(см.набор файлов для темы вордпресс, есть даже генераторы заготовок для верстки - например [туть](https://github.com/saxap/clean-wp-template)), и загрузите в папочку с темами wp-content/themes/ваша_тема, Вы увидите ее в админке (админ-панель > Внешний вид > Темы ) и сможете применить, то есть сайт наконец покажет, что именно в верстке Вы натянули и как