# Ultimate member не создаёт страницы

Tags: php, wordpress, ultimate-member

Растягиваю свою тему на wordpress. Нужен ЛК, со всем функционалом (вход/выход/регистрация и тд).

Активирую плагин ultimate member, а он не предлагает создать мне страницы. И я не понимаю, как мне подключить шаблоны и функционал um к моему сайту.

(Когда скачивала первый раз, он создал страницы, а я их удалила, потому что мешались на тот момент. Не помню, это было до или после растяжки своей темы.)

Comment: Что такое "растяжка" темы? Если плагин не создал их, то вы можете самостоятельно создать данные страницы и добавить на них необходимые шорткоды. Перейдите в настройки плагина, там сможете назначить страницы Ultimate Member -> Settings -> General. Затем перейдите в пункт Forms там найдете шорткоды, которые можно скопировать и добавить на нужные страницы. У плагина есть [документация](https://docs.ultimatemember.com/article/210-ultimate-member-shortcodes), где можно все почитать.

Comment: @Simon растяжка - это то, что у меня есть html+css+js, а сейчас я делаю из этого шаблон темы вордпресс. Ваш способ сработал, спасибо!

Comment: @Risha, я получил Ваше сообщение, но отвечу тут. 1 мне эти мелочи не интересны. 2. Настройки плагина не зависит от темы. 3. Про главную ошибку см https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/763199/233741

Comment: была аналогичная ситуация - нашел решение: Ultimate Member Default Pages NOT Installed? - FIXED!
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p01Pn4VBsCY