# Как вывести в случайном порядке посты в категории wp?

Tags: wordpress

Надо чтоб посты в категории выводились каждый раз при перезагрузке страницы в случайном порядке. Помогите пожалуйста найти правильное решение. Я использовала этот код, но по какой причине не работает, возможно я использую не тот файл.

```php
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'movie', 'orderby' => 'rand', 'posts_per_page' => '-1' ) );

if ( $query->have_posts() ):
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) :
        $query->the_post();
        //Echo the title, the excerpt, etc.
    endwhile;
endif;
```

Comment: Где выводились?  (вообще вряд ли стоит так делать). Что и как сейчас сделано? https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6688/233741

Comment: Я нашла loop в файле single.php И пыталась заменить  эту строку <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?> на то что выше. Может я не правильный файл выбрала. У меня шаблон стоит Woodmart

Comment: Во первых учим и правильно употребляем [терминологию](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%A7%D0%90%D0%92%D0%9E/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F), во вторых конечно не в  single.php. Учим [иерархию шаблонов](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%98%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2) (И о том, где этот код нужно тоже писать в вопросе ). А в третьих читаем [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/763199/233741)

Comment: Благодарю, буду учить :-)

Answer (score 0):

Неправильный шаблон `single.php` - это шаблон одиночной записи, хотя бы `archive.php` или `category.php`для списка категорий/таксономий/меток. Но и в них напрямую `WP_Query`, чтобы его модифицировать, c высокой вероятностью нет. Поэтому в `function.php` событие `pre_get_posts` чтобы повлиять на основной объект `WP_Query` и проверка шаблона `is_category()` чтобы не затронуть другие запросы:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'rand_category' );
function rand_category( $query ) {
    if( is_category() ) {
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'rand' );
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, вы спасли мой проект, всё работает, вы гений :-D

Comment: Заметила глюк после добавления кода, посты стали дублироваться в категории, но количество постов не увеличилось а осталось прежним.